# Create a unique device identifier on iOS 8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, udid

My app is a social networking app. You register and create a profile thus it needs a unique device identifier and since the UDID and the Mac addresses have been deprecated I am having troubles figuring out what to do. Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you search for an answer? There are many duplicates

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the unique device identifier - your options are `identifierForVendor` or the remote notification registration token.  Neither of these are lifetime invariant, but there isn't an identifier available to apps on iOS that is.

Comment: Hi Paul, I need a unique device identifier because I am creating a social networking app. The app does not relay in phone numbers of facebook profiles. You have to create a profile. How I was suggested to do it was when the user first time opens the app, the app takes token from keychain which is synced with iCloud so iTunes connect. The problem is that if you have 2 phone registered on the same iTunes you will have the same profile on both of them